# HackerRank says ~no response on stdout~. C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I wrote this solution for the absolute permutation problem on HackerRank. It works fine on dev-C++ but doesn't work on Hackerrank. I've found that the code produces output when I remove the abs_perm(). What's the problem here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int arr[100000];

int check(int n, int k)
{
    if ( (2*k == n) || (k == 0) || (n - 4*k == 0) )
        return 1;
    else if (k < n/2)
        return check(n - 4*k, k);
    else
        return 0;
}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;
}

void ini(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i+1;
    }
}

void abs_perm(int n, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[k+i]);
    }

    if (2*k == n)
        return;

    for (int i = n - 1; i > n - k - 1; i--)
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[i-k]);
    } 

    if (n - 4*k == 0)
        return;

    abs_perm(n - 4*k, k);
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    int N[T], K[T];
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        cin >> N[i] >> K[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        cout << N[i] << " " << K[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        if ( !check(N[i], K[i]) )
            cout << "-1\n";
        else
        {
            ini(N[i]);

            abs_perm(N[i], K[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < N[i]; j++)
            {
                cout << arr[j] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found a logical error in the code and now it works fine with the array. But I'll keep in mind your guys' advice while writing code from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Array is a structure to use when you know at compile time the dimension of your structure. What you wrote at the begin in abs_perm() is not correct for standard compilers (in fact you don't know the dimension of your array). You can use a std::vector or a std::list which allocate memory dynamically or (bad solution) you can allocate an array with dimension that certainly contains all elements you will put inside.